# "Waiting for table metadata lock” with MySQL

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

I am using Google Cloud SQL (5.5) and often happens "Waiting for table metadata lock".

I read [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/metadata-locking.html) and [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72332/what-could-cause-waiting-for-table-metadata-lock), and I checked general_log.

Below is snippet of general_log.

```
                 :
('2015-06-03 07:15:25','root[root] @ localhost []',1081,1791318620,'Close stmt',''),
('2015-06-03 07:15:25','root[root] @ localhost []',1081,1791318620,'Prepare','SELECT * FROM .....'),
('2015-06-03 07:15:25','root[root] @ localhost []',1081,1791318620,'Execute','SELECT * FROM .....'),
('2015-06-03 07:15:25','root[root] @ localhost []',1081,1791318620,'Close stmt',''),
('2015-06-03 07:15:25','root[root] @ localhost []',1081,1791318620,'Prepare','SELECT * FROM .....),
('2015-06-03 07:15:25','root[root] @ localhost []',1081,1791318620,'Execute','SELECT * FROM .....'),
('2015-06-03 07:15:25','root[root] @ localhost []',1081,1791318620,'Close stmt',''),
('2015-06-03 07:15:25','root[root] @ localhost []',1081,1791318620,'Prepare','SELECT * FROM .....'),
('2015-06-03 07:15:25','root[root] @ localhost []',1081,1791318620,'Execute','SELECT * FROM .....'),
('2015-06-03 07:15:25','root[root] @ localhost []',1081,1791318620,'Close stmt',''),
('2015-06-03 07:15:25','root[root] @ localhost []',1081,1791318620,'Prepare','SELECT * FROM .....'),
('2015-06-03 07:15:25','root[root] @ localhost []',1081,1791318620,'Execute','SELECT * FROM .....'),
('2015-06-03 07:17:11','[root] @ localhost []',2,1791318620,'Connect','root@localhost on mydb'),
('2015-06-03 07:17:11','[root] @ localhost []',3,1791318620,'Connect','root@localhost on mydb'),
('2015-06-03 07:17:32','root[root] @ localhost []',2,1791318620,'Query','set autocommit=1'),
('2015-06-03 07:17:32','root[root] @ localhost []',3,1791318620,'Query','set autocommit=1'),
('2015-06-03 07:17:32','root[root] @ localhost []',1,1791318620,'Query','set autocommit=1'),
('2015-06-03 07:17:32','root[root] @ localhost []',3,1791318620,'Query','SET sql_mode=\'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES\''),
('2015-06-03 07:17:32','root[root] @ localhost []',2,1791318620,'Query','SET sql_mode=\'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES\''),
('2015-06-03 07:17:32','root[root] @ localhost []',1,1791318620,'Query','SET sql_mode=\'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES\''),
('2015-06-03 07:17:32','root[root] @ localhost []',3,1791318620,'Query','commit'),
('2015-06-03 07:17:32','root[root] @ localhost []',2,1791318620,'Query','commit'),
('2015-06-03 07:17:32','root[root] @ localhost []',1,1791318620,'Query','commit'),
('2015-06-03 07:17:32','root[root] @ localhost []',3,1791318620,'Query','SET NAMES utf8mb4'),
('2015-06-03 07:17:32','root[root] @ localhost []',2,1791318620,'Query','SET NAMES utf8mb4'),
('2015-06-03 07:17:32','root[root] @ localhost []',1,1791318620,'Query','SET NAMES utf8mb4'),
('2015-06-03 07:17:32','[root] @ localhost []',4,1791318620,'Connect','root@localhost on mydb'),
('2015-06-03 07:17:32','[root] @ localhost []',5,1791318620,'Connect','root@localhost on mydb'),
('2015-06-03 07:17:33','root[root] @ localhost []',5,1791318620,'Query','set autocommit=1'),
('2015-06-03 07:17:33','root[root] @ localhost []',4,1791318620,'Query','set autocommit=1'),
('2015-06-03 07:17:33','root[root] @ localhost []',5,1791318620,'Query','SET sql_mode=\'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES\''),
('2015-06-03 07:17:33','root[root] @ localhost []',4,1791318620,'Query','SET sql_mode=\'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES\''),
('2015-06-03 07:17:33','root[root] @ localhost []',5,1791318620,'Query','commit'),
('2015-06-03 07:17:33','root[root] @ localhost []',4,1791318620,'Query','commit'),
('2015-06-03 07:17:33','root[root] @ localhost []',5,1791318620,'Query','SET NAMES utf8mb4'),
                 :
```

There are no log from 07:15:25 to 07:17:11 but my app was issuing queries and worked without problem.
Just around general_log resumes (07:17 or 07:18), my app stucked and `show processlist` shows "Waiting for table metadata lock."

I know DDL causes "Waiting for table metadata lock.", but I am sure I did not execute any DDL.

My guess is loss of general_log caused "Waiting for table metadata lock.", but I am not sure why log loss happened.

Is my guess right? If so, why loss happend?
Or is there any other cause?

**[Update]**
`show processlist` is like below.

```
+----+------+-----------------+------+---------+------+---------------------------------+-------------------+
| Id | User | Host            | db   | Command | Time | State                           | Info              |
+----+------+-----------------+------+---------+------+---------------------------------+-------------------+
|  1 | root | localhost       | mydb | Execute |  335 | Waiting for table metadata lock | SELECT * FROM ... |
|  2 | root | localhost       | mydb | Execute |  358 | Waiting for table metadata lock | SELECT * FROM ... |
|  4 | root | localhost       | mydb | Prepare |  359 | Opening table                   | NULL              |
|  6 | root | localhost       | mydb | Prepare |  347 | Waiting for table metadata lock | NULL              |
|  7 | root | localhost       | mydb | Execute |  346 | Waiting for table metadata lock | SELECT * FROM ... |
|  8 | root | localhost       | mydb | Execute |  335 | Waiting for table metadata lock | SELECT ...        |
|  9 | root | localhost       | mydb | Execute |  320 | Waiting for table metadata lock | SELECT ...        |
| 11 | root | localhost       | mydb | Execute |  299 | Waiting for table metadata lock | SELECT * FROM ... |
| 12 | root | localhost       | mydb | Prepare |  299 | Waiting for table metadata lock | NULL              |
| 13 | root | localhost       | mydb | Execute |  279 | Waiting for table metadata lock | SELECT * FROM ... |
| 14 | root | localhost       | mydb | Execute |  269 | Waiting for table metadata lock | SELECT * FROM ... |
| 16 | root | localhost       | mydb | Sleep   |  240 |                                 | NULL              |
| 17 | root | localhost       | mydb | Execute |  209 | Waiting for table metadata lock | SELECT * FROM ... |
| 19 | root | localhost       | mydb | Execute |  203 | Waiting for table metadata lock | SELECT ...        |
| 21 | root | localhost       | mydb | Execute |  200 | Waiting for table metadata lock | SELECT * FROM ... |
```

Comment: Only I and the app access the database.

Comment: other processes were running, all of them are either SELECT or NULL.

Comment: can you do a `show engine innodb status;` and look for the transaction section and post that?